# how to set samesite cookie token correctly in cookie browser response?

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, jwt, token

cookie token setting accessed via frontend and backend cancel each other

i am puzzle because the setting result cancel access each other

When i set cookie like this

```
            res.cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, { //send refresh token to client after log in
                httpOnly: true,
                maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, //1 day
                //secure : true // https protocol
                //samesite:'none'
```

i can get/generate refresh token via postman-like app, but i get warning like this (firefox)

```
Cookie “refresh_token” does not have a proper “SameSite” attribute value. Soon, cookies without the “SameSite” attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as “Lax”. This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the “SameSite=None“ attribute to it. To know more about the “SameSite“ attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
```

But when set cookie like this

```
            res.cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, { //send refresh token to client after log in
                httpOnly: true,
                maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, //1 day
                //secure : true // https protocol
                samesite:'none'
```

i could not not get/generate refresh token when tested via postman-like app

```
Error: "samesite" is not allowed in "options"
```

and there is no warning from firefox

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
 res.cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, { //send refresh token to client after log in
            httpOnly: true,
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, //1 day
            secure: true
            sameSite:'none'
```

Comment: still the same result :)

Comment: What framework are you using to code the backend?

Comment: i'm using nodejs - expressjs

Comment: It should work. Make sure to use sameSite:'none' instead of samesite:'none'